# Java getRGB doesnt read correct pixels

Tags: java

I just want to read the RGB values of a *basic 2x2 pixels* png file, but it returns the wrong RGB values. For example, the pixel at `x = 2` and `y = 2` was black, so it should return `0,0,0`, but it returns white as RGB values and i need to extend the image size itself to a higher resolution than 2x2, otherwise it wont recognize any pixels except `x = 1` and `y = 1`

```
public class Image
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        BufferedImage img = null;
        File f = null;

        //read image
        try{
          f = new File("image.png");
          img = ImageIO.read(f);
        }catch(IOException e){
          System.out.println(e);
        }

        int x = 2;
        int y = 2;

        int clr = img.getRGB(x, y);
        int red = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
        int green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
        int blue = clr & 0x000000ff;
        System.out.println("Red Color value = " + red);
        System.out.println("Green Color value = " + green);
        System.out.println("Blue Color value = " + blue);

    }
}
```

Comment: What mean `"returns white as RGB values"`? Can you show us what exactly return?

Comment: Are you sure it's 1-indexed and not 0-indexed?

Comment: Remember that the pixel in the top-left corner of the image is at (0, 0). If your image is only 2x2 pixels in size then (1, 1) would be the coordinate of the  bottom-right most pixel. You should also check whether your code to extract the individual color components is correct. To make sure you are not mistaken you can instantiate a java.awt.Color object with the rgba value returned by the getRGB method.

Comment: @DudeDoesThings Oh yeah thats a stupid mistake from me to forget that (0, 0) is the top left pixel. It works pefrectly fine now, thanks.